# Enabling CoffeeScript lexer in SciTE?

Tags: coffeescript, scite

I noticed there is a `LexCoffeeScript.cxx` file in the SciTE source code; however, SciTE does not seem to have a CoffeeScript menu option in its Languages menu.

Adding the option manually doesn't help -- there still isn't any syntax coloring.

Is there any way to enable the *built-in* lexer (instead of resorting to an external one)?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the CoffeeScript lexer is compiled in Scintilla but not used by SciTE. I mean that there is no `coffeescript.properties` file or any other file that would refer to the lexer. You cat try to create your own and set the lexer for file extension you use to `coffeescript`:

```
# Define SciTE settings for Coffeescript files.
file.patterns.coffeescript=*.coffee
filter.coffeescript=Coffeescript (coffee)|$(file.patterns.coffeescript)|
lexer.$(file.patterns.coffeescript)=coffeescript
...
```

Then you would define keywords, coloring styles and other stuff supported by the lexer - check out its sources. You can get inspiration in `cpp.properties`, e.g. (The lexer for C/C++ and similar languages is called `cpp`.) Here are supported lexical states:

```
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_DEFAULT=0
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_COMMENT=1
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_COMMENTLINE=2
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_COMMENTDOC=3
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_NUMBER=4
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_WORD=5
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_STRING=6
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_CHARACTER=7
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_UUID=8
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_PREPROCESSOR=9
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_OPERATOR=10
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_IDENTIFIER=11
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_STRINGEOL=12
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_VERBATIM=13
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_REGEX=14
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_COMMENTLINEDOC=15
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_WORD2=16
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_COMMENTDOCKEYWORD=17
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_COMMENTDOCKEYWORDERROR=18
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_GLOBALCLASS=19
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_STRINGRAW=20
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_TRIPLEVERBATIM=21
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_HASHQUOTEDSTRING=22
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_COMMENTBLOCK=22
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_VERBOSE_REGEX=23
val SCE_COFFEESCRIPT_VERBOSE_REGEX_COMMENT=24
```

All `.properties` files are loaded automatically by the line `import *` from `SciTEGlobal.properties`. You can also add `Coffeescript|coffee||\` to `menu.language` to get a new menu item in `Languages` and/or `*.coffee` to `source.files` to see the extnsion in the File Open dialog.

It is strange that the author did not provide the `.properties` file with the lexer. It can be that the JavaScript lexer can be used instead. You could ask about it in the [SciTE mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scite-interest/).

--- Ferda

Answer (score 1):

Ferda's answer is right on.

Here is a sample coffeescript.properties file to get started and save you some time...

```
# Define SciTE settings for Coffeescript files.
file.patterns.coffeescript=*.coffee
filter.coffeescript=Coffeescript (coffee)|$(file.patterns.coffeescript)|
lexer.$(file.patterns.coffeescript)=coffeescript

keywordclass.coffeescript=abstract boolean break byte case catch char class \
const continue debugger default delete do double else enum export extends \
final finally float for function goto if implements import in instanceof \
int interface long native new package private protected public \
return short static super switch synchronized this throw throws \
transient try typeof var void volatile while with
keywords.$(file.patterns.coffeescript)=$(keywordclass.coffeescript)

keywordclass2.coffeescript=$
keywords2.$(file.patterns.coffeescript)=$(keywordclass2.coffeescript)

# White space 
style.coffeescript.0=fore:#808080
# Comment: ### ###
style.coffeescript.1=$(colour.code.comment.box),$(font.code.comment.box)
# Line Comment: #
style.coffeescript.2=$(colour.code.comment.line),$(font.code.comment.line)
# Doc comment: block comments beginning with /** or /*!
style.coffeescript.3=$(colour.code.comment.doc),$(font.code.comment.doc)
# Number
style.coffeescript.4=$(colour.number)
# Keyword
style.coffeescript.5=$(colour.keyword),bold
# Double quoted string
style.coffeescript.6=$(colour.string)
# Single quoted string
style.coffeescript.7=$(colour.char)
# UUIDs (only in IDL)
style.coffeescript.8=fore:#804080
# Preprocessor
style.coffeescript.9=$(colour.preproc)
# Operators
style.coffeescript.10=fore:#FF6600,bold
# Identifiers
style.coffeescript.11=fore:#FF1493
# End of line where string is not closed
style.coffeescript.12=fore:#000000,$(font.monospace),back:#E0C0E0,eolfilled
# Verbatim strings 
style.coffeescript.13=fore:#007F00,$(font.monospace),back:#E0FFE0,eolfilled
# Regular expressions for JavaScript
style.coffeescript.14=fore:#3F7F3F,$(font.monospace),back:#E0F0FF,eolfilled
# Doc Comment Line: line comments beginning with /// or //!.
style.coffeescript.15=$(colour.code.comment.doc),$(font.code.comment.doc)
# Keywords2
style.coffeescript.16=fore:#B00040
# Comment keyword
style.coffeescript.17=fore:#3060A0,$(font.code.comment.doc)
# Comment keyword error
style.coffeescript.18=fore:#804020,$(font.code.comment.doc)
# Raw strings 
style.coffeescript.20=$(colour.string),back:#FFF3FF,eolfilled
# Triple-quoted strings
style.coffeescript.21=$(font.monospace),fore:#007F00,back:#E0FFE0,eolfilled
# Hash-quoted strings for Pike
style.coffeescript.22=$(font.monospace),fore:#007F00,back:#E7FFD7,eolfilled
# Verbose Regex
style.coffeescript.23=fore:#659900
# Verbose Regex Comment
style.coffeescript.24=$(colour.code.comment.doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this line in your `SciTEGlobal.properties` file. Which can be opened in the Options menu in SciTE by clicking `Open Global Options File`.

```
import lexers/[dir]
```

Where `[dir]` is the location of the `LexCoffeeScript.cxx` file in the lexers directory in `/usr/share/scite/`.

**UPDATE**
Tried this myself, my installation of SciTE doesn't have any CoffeeScript cxx file so I downloaded the scintillua package from [here](http://code.google.com/p/scintillua/) which is packaged with an `lua` coffeescript lexer. Following the above instruction to install it and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, you're importing a *C++* file from SciTE? Are you sure that's the way to do it?

Comment: @Mehrdad Updated my answer with what I did. I couldn't find a `.cxx` file in my source.

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work (or make much sense). Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Did you notice my question asked about enabling the ***built-in** lexer*, and **not** an external one?

Comment: I did, but I couldn't work it out :( This is the only resource I could find: http://www.scintilla.org/SciTELexer.html

Comment: Well the *only* reason I posted this was that I specifically wanted to enable the *built-in* one, so this doesn't really help unfortunately. :\